# C#- JSON escape \n character to \\n character

Tags: c#, json, json.net, escaping, newline

I want to replace the \n character in my JSON to \\n. I want to do this because the \n character in my JSON is getting parsed as a newline(whitespace) in the source where I am loading it. I want it to remain as a text character- \n. Escaping the \n using another \ works i.e. converting all \n to \\n in my JSON.

So I want to find the best way to achieve this.I am using the NewtonSoft JSON library in C# to serialize the JSON. Is there any method in this or some other JSON SDK which I can use to escape the \n characters in my JSON?

JSON that I have-

```
{
        "Name": "KeyName",
        "Value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\n<tokens xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"abc.com">\n  <properties>\n    <property id=\"x\" range=\"true\">y</property>\n    <property id=\"x\" range=\"true\">y</property>\n     </properties>\n</tokens>"
}
```

Text file that is getting generated after conversion from JSON-

```
KeyName|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<tokens xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="abc.com">
  <properties>
    <property id="3" range="true">4</property>
    <property id="2" range="true">50</property>
  </properties>
</tokens>
```

Text File I need-

```
KeyName|<tokens xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="abc.com">\n  <properties>\n    <property id="2" range="true">50</property>\n    <property id="3" range="true">1</property>\n </properties>\n</tokens>
```

This **\n** in the JSON is creating issues as its getting parsed as a new line in the text file I am generating and I need it as '\n' character in text file. Please note that I don't have control over the tool which I am using to convert the JSON to text but I can change the JSON and changing '\n' to '\\n' in the JSON is works, i.e. it is coming as a '\n' in the text file which is generated.

Comment: It's kinda weird that `/n` is being parsed as a new line, where almost everything uses backslashes as the escape character, and as such it'd be `\n`. But anyways, the most efficient way is to just `json = json.Replace("/n", "//n");`

Comment: This is a mistake at my end, its supposed to be \n only. Editing the question! Thank you

Comment: Ok, so just `json = json.Replace("\n", "\\n")`, I don't think you want/ need HTML escaping

Comment: I am worried about the performance cost of this operation through replace, as the data will be huge. I was hoping that there might be a JSON encoding property or something which does this more efficiently.

Comment: Again, this is strange, as Newtonsoft will anyway do this, see fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/cT5ZON. I suspect there is a problem of double-decoding going on here, but we don't know without seeing the code

Comment: @Charlieface Actually the JSON does have \\n but the JSON in text visualiser or in the Azure Blob where I am storing it shows \n. Because of this, in the next step of processing it gets parsed as newline. Changing \n to \\n in the Blob rectifies the issue.

Comment: Updated the Question with the JSONs for better quality

Comment: So you have xml containing new lines, in a json string with those newlines escaped (as they should be), in a c# string which I assume you are viewing in the VS Debugger? The VS Debugger will escape those `\\` *again*. That looks correct. So, why do you see this as a problem? In other words, what actual problem are you trying to solve here? Are you trying to use this json in a c#/javascript string literal?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The problem here is that when I am uploading the JSON to Azure Blob it comes up as a '\n' which is also what I see in the VS debugger. When I am trying to convert this JSON to txt file( further processing using Azure Synapse) the '\n' characters are getting parsed as new lines, while I want them to stay as '\n'. I checked and if I change the Blob JSON to have '\\n', the JSON to txt file conversion works fine, i.e. I get '\n' in the text file.

Comment: Then add that context, with examples to the question.

Comment: The blob of text above marked "JSON after the serialization is done" is not actually what is contained in the string. It is how the debugger visualizes it, making it look like a *literal* piece of C# code. To view it, paste into the Immediate Window and press Enter. You will see it actually does *not* contain `\\n` it contains `\n`, because the XML you are encoding in the JSON contains *actual* newlines. It would not be valid XML otherwise. So when you are parsing the XML out from the JSON, you are viewing it with newlines, because that is what the XML *actually* contains. There is no .....

Comment: .... problem here, the XML is *supposed* to have newlines. Unless you want to compile this string directly into a C# code file, it all looks to be correct

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, that explains a lot. But my problem still stands, I am trying to convert this JSON (which contains this XML) to a text file and the generated text file has actual new lines (whitespaces). I need it to contain '\n' because it breaks the flow ahead if it contains new lines. I don't have control over the conversion from JSON to text file with the tool I am using, but I can change the JSON if possible. I have seen that adding another '\' in the XML of the JSON i.e. changing '\n' to '\\n' works, i.e. the text file generated has '\n' and not actual new lines.

Comment: I have updated the Question with better context.

Comment: It sounds like you need to generate your text file like this `"KeyName|" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.KeyName).Trim('"')` in other words you only want that part to be serialized. Do not deserialize this, it will not be valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

The Newtonsoft [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_stringescapehandling.htm) says that you can choose to serialize escaping different characters.

For your particular case I think you want to use `EscapeHtml`.